# Severe performance issues with Expo when using third party module

Tags: expo, react-native

I am trying to use [this third party module](https://github.com/DuDigital/react-native-zoomable-view) with my Expo app but, as shown below, I am getting some severe performance issues with the following error being logged in the console

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `type` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html for more information.
```

I am using the exact same code that is used in [the example](https://github.com/DuDigital/react-native-zoomable-view#expo-snack-example) aside from just removing the image and some text, along with having react navigation set up with bottom tabs.

The issue is the same if I try to run the app on the Expo Go app on my mobile device.

[image: 3]